# How to use youtube video as background in wordpress without watermarks and controls

Tags: wordpress, video

Is there a way to embed youtube video in wordpress site as background without youtube watermarks and watch later ...etc? I am using embed options but it still shows when first loaded.
I am using acf pro so installing basic plugins won't work.

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/video-id?controls=0&showinfo=0&rel=0&autoplay=1&mute=1&playsinline=1&playlist=video-id&loop=1"
      frameborder="0"
      allow = "autoplay"
      allowfullscreen
      class="w-full h-full"
    ></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following approach:

- **Disable Annotations**: Add '**&iv_load_policy=3**' to your YouTube URL in the iframe code. This will disable annotations, which can include watermarks and other player controls.

Here's your modified code:

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/video-id?controls=0&showinfo=0&rel=0&autoplay=1&mute=1&playsinline=1&playlist=video-id&loop=1&iv_load_policy=3"
      frameborder="0"
      allow="autoplay"
      allowfullscreen
      class="w-full h-full"
    ></iframe>
```

This should load the video without the watermarks and controls initially. Keep in mind that YouTube may update their features, so it's a good idea to periodically check if this method still works as expected.